# size functions and thread-safety in C++

Tags: c++, list, thread-safety, constants

I wonder if size functions (size, length or whatever) are thread safe? They usually just return some private size member, as I understand. I really doubt they do any sort of calculations. They all are marked as const but are they thread-safe? for example *std::list::size*?

I have a lock-protected function for writing and another for reading (also lock-protected) but I wonder if my *count* function should also be lock-protected? IMO, it looks like a waste of response time. I don't think it may break any iterators or fail if some member is being removed from the list at the same time (as same, as possible).

Comment: `count` *is* reading. If you lock for other read operations, why wouldn't you lock for `count`? What makes it special?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it needs to be protected by a lock. Let's say that your implementation's `std::list::size` is a 32-bit value but on your platform 32-bit reads are not atomic, they take 2 16-bit reads. In this case, a second thread may interrupt the first that was reading the size after the first read has occurred, update the size variable and then when the second 16-bit read takes place you may get a real messed up value for size.

Comment: That explained why it's not thread-safe very well. Thank you.

Comment: @Pijusn and Kerrek SB, answers are completely contradictory.

Comment: Even back in 2012, how many 16-bit systems were in use? It may have been better to say that treating `size()` like it's thread-safe harms _portability_

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not thread-safe. The standard containers are simply not thread-safe, period.

There is however a limited amount of thread safety: If every thread accesses a *different* element, and no element is accessed by two distinct threads at any given time, then that's fine. However, any operation that mutates the container itself (insert, erase) is not thread-safe and *must* be synchronized. Consequently, iterators and references may lose their validity, and `size()` is similarly affected.

In other words,if you separate all operations that mutate the container from those that don't, then while you're not mutating, you *can* safely call `size()` from multiple threads.

Comment: The statement that the standard containers are "simply not thread-safe, period" is **very** misleading! They provide a very reasonable form of thread-safety. Just because some people wish for a kind of thread-safety where they can live without caring for thrads while getting all the benefits doesn't mean they are not thread-safe! The fact that people don't understand that access even to a primitive value requires synchronization is part of the problem they have with threading.